# Single nav-link in navbar not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, nav

I just started using Visual Studio Code to develop a business website. I have most of the homepage done but for some reason the Account tab in my navbar doesn't open. It doesn't even register when I click on it and I do have an Account.html page created already and it's linked to the homepage html but it just doesn't open. All other nav-links work fine like my Products link and Cart link. I should also mention that the Account link does open and redirect me to it when I click on it from any other page I'm on. For example when I'm on the Products page and click on the Account link in the navbar, it opens up immediately.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Here's the HomePage code(Index_HtmlPage.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Box icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" />

<!-- Custom StyleSheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />
<title>Atomic Bouncy Website</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Header -->
<header id="home" class="header">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="navigation container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Atomic Bouncy</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>Atomic Bouncy</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="close">
                        <i class="bx bx-x"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="Index_HtmlPage.html" class="nav-link scroll-link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="Product_HtmlPage.html" class="nav-link">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about" class="nav-link scroll-link">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link scroll-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="Account_HtmlPage.html" class="nav-link scroll-link">Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="Cart_HtmlPage.html" class="nav-link icon"><i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <a href="Cart_HtmlPage.html" class="cart-icon">
                <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i>
            </a>

            <div class="hamburger">
                <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Hero -->
    <img src="images/Heroimage.png" alt="" class="hero-img" />

    <div class="hero-content">
        <h2><span class="discount">30% </span>DISCOUNT</h2>
        <h1>
            <span>Birthday Vibes</span>
            <span>mode on</span>
        </h1>
        <a class="btn" href="#">Book now</a>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Main -->
<main>
    <section class="advert section">
        <div class="advert-center container">
            <div class="advert-box">
                <div class="dotted">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>
                            Girls <br />
                            Clothing
                        </h2>
                        <h4>Worlds Best Brands</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/advert1.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="advert-box">
                <div class="dotted">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>
                            Summer <br />
                            Clothing
                        </h2>
                        <h4>Worlds Best Brands</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/advert2.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="advert-box">
                <div class="dotted">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>
                            Boys <br />
                            Clothing
                        </h2>
                        <h4>Worlds Best Brands</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/advert3.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Featured -->
    <section class="section featured">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Featured Products</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="product-center container">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-header">
                    <img src="JC Images/JC Item 1.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <span><i class="bx bx-heart"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-search"></i></span>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h3>Disco Party Castle</h3>
                    </a>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bx-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="price">R500</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-header">
                    <img src="JC Images/JC Item 2.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <span><i class="bx bx-heart"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-search"></i></span>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a href="#"><h3>Princess Party 'N Slide</h3></a>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bx-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="price">R900</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-header">
                    <img src="JC Images/JC Item 3.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <span><i class="bx bx-heart"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-search"></i></span>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a href="#"><h3>Jungle Party Castle</h3></a>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bx-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="price">R600</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-header">
                    <img src="JC Images/JC Item 4.jpg" alt="">

                    <ul class="icons">
                        <span><i class="bx bx-heart"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="bx bx-search"></i></span>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="product-footer">
                    <a href="#"><h3>Football Shootout Castle</h3></a>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                        <i class="bx bx-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="price">R450</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>        
</main> 
<!-- GSAP -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Script -->
<script src="Index_JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've left most of the unnecessary CSS and here's just the CSS for the header and nav.
Here's the Main StyleSheet (StyleSheet.css):

```
:root {
  --white: #fff;
  --black: #222;
  --pink: #f60091;
  --grey: #444;
  --grey2: #959595;
  --grey-alt: #d1e2e9;
  --yellow: #ffd800;
  --green: #59b210;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #243a6f;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-md {
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 3rem;
  }

  .container-md {
    padding: 0 3rem;
  }
}

/* Header */
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--grey-alt);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  padding: 1.6rem 0;
}

.nav.fix-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #243a6f;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav.fix-nav .nav-link,
.nav.fix-nav .logo,
.nav.fix-nav .cart-icon,
.nav.fix-nav .hamburger {
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-link:link,
.nav-link:visited {
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link.icon {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.top-nav {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.cart-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 40rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  .menu.show {
    left: 0;
  }

  .top-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #243a6f;
    padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
  }

  .top-nav .logo {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .top-nav .close {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .cart-icon {
    display: block;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav-link:link,
  .nav-link:visited {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }

  .nav.fix-nav .nav-link {
    color: #243a6f;
  }

  .nav-list {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
  }

  body.show::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 4;
  }

  .nav.show {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }

  .nav-link.icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Hero */
.header .hero-img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  right: -5%;
  height: 60rem;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(25%, -50%);
}

.hero-content h2 {
  color: #b888ff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.hero-content .discount {
  color: #fbb419;
}

.hero-content h1 span {
  color: #253b70;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #f1f1f1, 4px 4px 0 #f1f1f1;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fc7c7c;
  padding: 1.2rem 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .header .hero-img {
    right: -20%;
  }

  .hero-content {
    transform: translate(20%, -50%);
  }

  .hero-content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .hero-content h1 span {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 996px) {
  .header {
    min-height: 70vh;
  }

  .header .hero-img {
    height: 40rem;
    right: -10%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 567px) {
  .header {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }

  .header .hero-img {
    height: 40rem;
    bottom: -15%;
  }

  .hero-content {
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(15%, -50%);
  }

  .header .hero-img {
    right: 0%;
  }

  .hero-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }

  .hero-content h1 span {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

  .hero-content a {
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
  }
}
```

Thank You for the help!

Comment: Looks like "scroll-link" might be the culprit, as that is the only difference.

Comment: @GhostPengy so do you think I remove the "scroll-link"?

Comment: Try and see what happens. Otherwise, we would need a full page to debug (with all of javascript). Since HTML is fine, and CSS itself cannot affect what happens when you click on a link.

Comment: @GhostPengy thanks so much! It seems that was the case, I removed the scroll-links and it worked. Much appreciated.